# がいると? Condtional to express "When x is around"

Tags: translation, particle-と, conditionals

I've seen this a few times lately and I wanted to make sure I get it. Most recently I saw it on a video with an animal's thoughts narrated. It said この人間がいると安心できない。I take this as meaning "When this human is here I can't feel relieved/I can't feel relieved if this human is around". So, ～がいると means something to the effect of "when x exists/if x exists"?　Would this be the most common way to talk about "you" and specific people being around as well? Such as 君がいると and さくらがいると?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you're having trouble with. Is your question more about the conditional と, or the use of the verb [居]{い}る ?

Comment: I guess it was more about seeking confirmation about using it with the conditional. I wanted to make sure it can be used to express "when someone is around" such as さくらがいると

Comment: There are multiple kinds of conditional. It’s hard to tell which is the “most common.” Which one to use depends on what you want to say.

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains more than a couple of grammar peculiarities. The meaning is "I feel insecure whenever this person is around.",
 BUT,
"この人間” (this person) is someone close to the speaker at that time, so that your phrase is mostly supposed to be uttered by someone in a group, while someone in the group is speaking or doing something.

It is a phrase that could be uttered by a girl who feels somewhat assaulted by somebody.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly:

Yes, (I don't know if most common, but) at least I think it does sound pretty natural if someone says e.g.: 君が[e.g.近くに]いると安心できない

As to the この人, at least I'd say that you esp. in the contexts as above, can also use it to refer to yourself, like in;

[分かってるよ、]この人がいると安心出来ない[っすよね。]